# Getting the Username of user from Pointer (Parse.com)

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have a class called "Chat" and one of the columns is a pointer to the user that has created the object. How do I get that user's username value in a query?
I need the query to retrieve objects from the "Chat" class and add them to an array and instead of adding the user id, I would like it to add the username.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryUserId = result["user"] as PFUser
self.nameString = queryUserId.username
```